# Does apple accept iOS application without new user registration in application?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I am developing iOS application which is communicating with our private server and I want to publish it on iTunes but wanted to provide access to specific people only. For that I have created a login screen without new user registration screen and will provide credentials to that specific people. So my question is:

1. Is apple developer will accept the application without new user registration functionality in mobile application?
2. If yes, then could you please provide us sample applications link from iTunes application which does not have new user registration but needed a login credential to access the application.

Comment: I dont have active examples of this right now, but the way you do this is create a locked down invite screen where an invite code needs to be entered before you can register as a user

Comment: this will pass just fine with the Apple store, but you need to make sure that you have a way for them to reivew it, and you should probably explain the reasons behind it, there's government apps on the ituens store that won't give you access at all, and there's a whole hoard of apps from various publishers that are private as well and also sitting on ituens, butyou need an invite code

Comment: Actually I have made one like this, guess what V1.0 was approved and V1.1 was rejected. So this is still strange to me. Good Luck!!!

Comment: im pretty sure any enterprise app would be like this, dont know of examples though

Comment: probably a lot of banking apps are like this as well

Comment: I added an example in my answer below, like you requested. There are quite a few more out there...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, this probably won't prevent your app from being approved. However, you have to make sure that you provide a valid username/password for testing with you submit the app for review, so that Apple's review team can actually review it. You can input these details in the DEMO ACCOUNT section of the app submission page (on the bottom). Good Luck!

**EDIT:**

You can checkout the [Bank of America app](https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/bank-america-mobile-banking/id284847138?mt=8). It's not necessarily a great app, but you can take it as an example of an approved app that only allows login and doesn't support new user registration.